# How to track mouse movement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, passwords

I have a little problem, i can't figure out how to track mouse position and update a function every time it moves, this is the code that i want to modify so it updates;

```js
function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}

console.log(makeid());
```

Hopefully one of the smart people out there could help me!

Comment: `update a function every time it moves` I don't understand. can you please explain your requirement?

Comment: What does the code you posted have to do with mouse movements? You want to see if it is a person and not a computer that triggers the function?  Also [did you look](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+track+mouse+movements+site:stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: @BadPiggie I mean that so every time my code tracks mouse movement the password regenerates.

Comment: Have you investigated the various mouse events? mouse move event is described at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event

Comment: Thank you! @BadPiggie for helping me!!!!

Comment: @MaximShevchenko Please comment under the answer, if  you are asking anything regarding the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @BadPiggie I mean that so every time my code tracks mouse movement the
> password regenerates.

As you mentioned in the comment, If you want to trigger the `makeid` evener the mouse move, You can listen to `mousemove` event on `window`

```js
function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}

function mouseMoveEventHandler() {
  console.log(makeid());
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveEventHandler);
```

Comment: If there any chance of adding delay?

Comment: @MaximShevchenko Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: @MaximShevchenko Also for more helper functions like throttling and all, Consider using https://lodash.com/ (Optional)

Comment: I would love to, but i don't have 15 rep.